# Too many open files exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

We are developing a business app with Xamarin.iOS, the app uses the following libraries: MVVMCross, HttpClient and ModernHttpClient. The app is online and offline and must download many documents, data and jsons to display the necessary contents.

We must download ~1500 pdf documents and images (from 10kB to 10MB) and ~1500 jsons (from 1kB to 600kB in size). While the app is downloading the consumed memory constantly increase, profiler says that i've many byte[] around but i use streams for download. In download code i had to write a custom file manager because with System.IO.File i had 'Too many open files exception'. The download is done with 4 concurrent threads.

If i handle file save through System.IO.File i got "Too many open files exception" if i use NSFileManager the app consumes a lot of memory (profiler says that i've many byte[] around but i use streams for download, as said before).

What can i do? Am i missing something?

The download code is as follow:

```
using (var client = HttpClientFactory.Create())
{
        using (var content = await client.GetStreamWithRetryAsync("url/" +id + "?versione=" + versione, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (!StorageService.StoreJsonToTemp(codiceStorage, content))
                            return new ServiceResponse<bool>(new Exception("Not saved"));
         }
}
```

Storage code is as follow:

```
public bool WriteFile(string path, Stream stream)
        {
            using (stream)
            {
                using (var data = NSData.FromStream(stream))
                {
                    if (!data.Save(GetRealPath(path), false))
                        return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
```

I don't know how to fix this problem because with both approaches i have a lot of cons. Thank you

Any idea?

Comment: Were you closing the stream that you passed into WriteFile?